# Images from library not displayed in IE8, but shown in Chrome & Firefox

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I have added a image in SiteAssets library. I have referred to that image in my aspx page. While redering page, image is not rendered in IE. While same image is rendered correctly in Chrome / Firefox . Am I missing something here?

Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: Ctrl + R, the results are probably cached.

Comment: Nope.. I tried to clear the cache. but no success.

Comment: Can you post a sample of the HTML output that works in FF but not in IE? Also, have you examined the request/response results using an HTTP debugger like Fiddler?

Comment: I fired up fiddler & found that I am getting 401 response in both IE & Chrome. But Chrome is showing image, while IE is not.

Comment: Thanks everybody for your help. It seems that this was some issue related to my site collection. I created new site collection and deployed my site on it and it worked.... Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

Just to give an update if anyone face this issue-
The issue was with image only. Image was distorted. I reopened the image in a photo editor and saved it. Uplaoded the image in library. Then it worked for all the browsers.

Answer (score -1):

"Microsoft Internet Explorer 8.0 dropped support for jpeg images saved as CMYK and now only supports images saved in RGB mode. "

This was the problem!
Source:http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch001283.htm

If this issue exists, the CMYK image will appear as a red X or broken image in Internet Explorer. However, opening this page in Chrome or Firefox should show both images. If both images are visible to Internet Explorer, this is not the issue with your version of Internet Explorer.

**Fixing this issue**

Image editors such as Adobe Photoshop, The GIMP, and others is capable of identifying if a jpg image is a CMYK image and saving a CMYK jpg as a RGB jpg. Online services can also be used to convert any JPG image into a RGB image.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please do not add reference link as only answer. Since it might not exist in future.